# Context Dependency Inhections in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I'm new to Context Dependency Injections in Java EE (I'm on EE 6), and I would like to please ask about something I ran into:

Let's say you declare this annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Qualifier
public @interface MaxPassengers {}
```

In a different class I say that the **getMaxPassengers** method produces the value to be injected when the **@MaxPassengers** annotation is used:

```
public class AirplaneInformation implements Serializable {
    @Produces @MaxPassengers Integer getMaxPassengers() {
        return 250;
    }
}
```

In yet a third class, I inject the @MaxPassengers into a variable:

```
@MaxPassengers
@Inject
private Integer maxPassengers;
```

All this work great, but here's the twist:

What if I want change the signature of 
    **@Produces @MaxPassengers Integer getMaxPassengers()**
to
    **@Produces @MaxPassengers Integer getMaxPassengers(String planeType)**

And return the a dynamic value of **maxPassengers** based on the **planeType**.

I'm wondering if this can be done, and if so, how do I change the following annotation

```
@MaxPassengers
@Inject
private Integer maxPassengers;
```

to also supply the **planeType** argument.

Thank you for your help,
-Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this is done is to add the `planeType` to the qualifier as `@NonBinding`.  You would then pass in an `InjectionPoint` object to your method and look up the `MaxPassengers` this way: `injectionPoint.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(MaxPassengers.class);`

If you want to pull this up at runtime, you would use an `Instance` object an an `AnnotationLiteral` of your `MaxPassengers`, something like this:

```
@Inject @Any
private Instance<Integer> integerInstance;


...

integerInstance.select(new MaxPassengersLiteral("foo")).get();
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is `@Any` required or can this be made faster by only injecting `@MaxPassengers`?

Comment: `Any` is required as the injection point doesn't know what is going to be injected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer John. My sense is that you are a true expert of Java EE. To be perfectly honest I have to learn a bit more CDI before I can fully understand what you meant. I learned all that can be learned about CDI from the "Java EE 6 Tutorial Basic Concepts" book and then came up with airline small proof of concept project. This week I'll read the CDI chapter in "Beginning EJB 3" and then hopefully I'll know a bit more...